# Why are carriage returns deleted in the editor?

Tags: editor

I'm not sure why this is happening but after I add a blank line between paragraphs and click update or go to text view and back to visual, the blank lines are gone.  I can't put any space between lines.

Any one know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The blank lines are removed by WordPress after saving the post.

If you have to use blank lines, you can instead use following html

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`